# How to queue build pipeline as task from release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There is a build pipeline that someone else owns in the project (it runs one shell script task doesn't publish anything). I own a release pipeline and want to run a job that effectively "queues" their build pipeline. I cannot add an extension to do this. Regardless of how we got to this point or best practices, is there a way to accomplish triggering a build of their build pipeline from a job in the release pipeline in azure devops? Thank you.

Comment: Why not create a task group that is shared between their build definition and your release definition that runs the shell script?

Comment: @DanielMann thank you for your quick reply. This is definitely one of the ways I could do it, but ideally I do not change anything about their build pipeline while still capturing future changes - changing their build pipeline to use the task group would give my release pipeline future changes but would require their build pipeline to change

Comment: @PaulEpperson how about [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) extension  ?This way it will help you to queue the build

Comment: Sorry @Jayendran that is the extension I wanted to use but as I put in the question i cannot use extensions (just an organization thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PowerShell script to queue the build with REST API:

```
 $BuildDefinitonId = {YourBuildDefinitonID}
 try
 {
 $body = @{ definition = @{id = $BuildDefinitonId} }
 $requestUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1" 
 $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Uri $requestUrl -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) -UseDefaultCredentials
 }
 catch
 {
  Write-Host "Failed to trigger build {$BuildDefinitonId}, Exception: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
 }
```

So in the release pipeline add a PowerShell task with this script:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Shayki. I will try and if it works I will accept your answer.